# How to make regular expressions in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

How to make regular expression in PHP? Can anyone guide me to the basic rules to make regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

php.net in general has the entire documentation for the php language.  It's probably one of the more valuable resources available.

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be the PHP manual for regular expressions:

**[Regular Expressions (Perl-Compatible)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)**

There are three major use cases for regular expressions:

- Searching: [preg_match](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
- Replacing: [preg_replace](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- Splitting: [preg_split](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info) and its [PHP section](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) for details on how to use regexes in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

See the [book of PHP’s PCRE functions](http://php.net/book.pcre), in particular the chapter on [PCRE’s pattern syntax](http://php.net/pcre.pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple tutorials on using regular expressions in PHP that will get you started:

- [Regular Expressions (Part1) - Basic Syntax](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/regular-expressions-part1---basic-syntax)
- [PHP regular expression tutorial](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-regular-expression.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will get basic details of expression content here

Table 1. Common regex operators

1. . (period)         Match any single character
2. ^ (caret)          Match the empty string that occurs at the beginning of a line or string
3. $ (dollar sign)    Match the empty string that occurs at the end of a line
4. A                  Match an uppercase letter A
5. a                  Match a lowercase letter a
6. \d                 Match any single digit
7. \D                 Match any single nondigit character
8. \w                 Match any single alphanumeric character; a synonym is [:alnum:]
9. [A-E]          Match any of uppercase A, B, C, D, or E
10. [^A-E]        Match any character except uppercase A, B, C, D, or E
11. X?                Match none or one capital letter X
12. X*                Match zero or more capital Xes
13. X+                Match one or more capital Xes
14. X{n}          Match exactly n capital Xes
15. X{n,m}        Match at least n and no more than m capital Xes; if you omit m, the expression tries to match at least nXes
16. (abc|def)+        Match a sequence of at least one abc and def;abc and def would match

for more details use following link
[Mastering regular expressions in PHP](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-regex1/)